# Plateau on weighted pullups

Tags: pull-ups, beginners

I got stuck on  weighted pullups today(tried 3x5 with 3 extra pounds). It was 5/5/2. I rested 5 minutes in between sets. I started weighted pullups Tuesday and completed the 5/5/5 with 2 extra pounds (although the last set was hard) and same amount of rest between sets. Ideally, I'd like to continue training weighted pullups 3 times a week.

I kept my diet the same(if anything I lost weight) 23,5" 11',M,157 pounds

Do I need to decrease rest time? How do I get better at this and still keep frequency the same or do I need to increase frequency? Do I need to increase volume? Should I just progress slower, at 0.5 pounds?

Sorry for the dumb question. Not a repeat question, I'm not going for a one-arm pullup.

Comment: That question, although titled similarly, is about going after one arm pullups. That's a different progression path and all the answers speak to that.

Answer (score 1):

Pullups are like any other compound exercise like the squat, deadlift, overhead press, or lunge.

I think you should start familiarizing yourself with [overload programming](http://breakingmuscle.com/strength-conditioning/7-markers-of-a-solid-strength-program). Basically, the question you're asking "*how do I get stronger?*" has been asked many times before and there are solid answers that are time proven. There are also a lot of people wasting time by not using a good program. This includes routines you put together yourself and that are available in most magazines.

Rather than attempt to one-up world famous coaches, I'll layout the [Starting Strength Novice Program](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs):

**Monday**

- 3x5 Squat
- 3x5 Bench press / Press (Alternating)
- [Chin-ups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/LatissimusDorsi/BWUnderhandChinup.html): 3 sets to failure or add weight if completing more than 15 reps

**Wednesday**

- 3x5 [Squat](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BBSquat.html)
- 3x5 [Press](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/BBMilitaryPress.html) / [Bench Press](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BBBenchPress.html) (Alternating)
- 1x5 [Deadlift](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/ErectorSpinae/BBDeadlift.html)

**Friday**

- 3x5 Squat
- 3x5 Bench Press / Press (Alternating)
- [Pull-ups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/LatissimusDorsi/BWPullup.html): 3 sets to failure or add weight if completing more than 15 reps

I don't think anyone is going to be able to give you a program different from above that will make you stronger in any given amount of time. I'm assuming this is related to [your previous question about weighted pullups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/28430/7091).